# get stored Database variables on php login session

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phpmyadmin, session-variables

i would like to read $Session[] variables on my profile page but im having issues while trying it.
this is my php script on my login file

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['LoginBtn']))
    {
      $username = $_POST['username'];
      $password = $_POST['password'];
      if (empty($username) || empty($password))
      {
        $show -> showError("please fill out all the fields");
      }
      else
      {
        $SQLCheckUser = $odb -> prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Account` WHERE `username` = :user AND `password` = :password LIMIT 1");
        $SQLCheckUser -> execute(array(':user' => $username, ':password' => hash('SHA512', $password)));
        $loginCheck = $SQLCheckUser -> fetchColumn(0);
        if ($loginCheck)
        {

          $SQLGetID = $odb -> prepare("SELECT `ID`, FROM `Account` WHERE `username` = :username LIMIT 1");
          $SQLGetID -> execute(array(':username' => $username));

          $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

          $_SESSION['ID'] = $SQLGetID -> fetchColumn(0);
          $show -> showSuccess('Willkommen... <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=index.php">');
        }
        else
        {
          $show -> showError('user was not found!');
        }
      }
    }
    ?>
```

in the Database on Account i have variables like, username, password, firstname, lastname, adress and i would like to display them on the profile.php page for example like this

```
          <h4 class="profile-user"><?php echo $_SESSION['firstname']; ?></h4>
          <p class="profile-job"><?php echo $_SESSION['lastname']; ?></p>
          <p class="profile-job"><?php echo $_SESSION['adress'];?></p>
```

how could i solve this issue ?
page contains a php file starting a session with

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

and a db connection

```
<?php
$show = new show();
$user = new user($odb);
$status = new status($odb);
class show
{
function showError($error)
{
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger"><a class="close" data-                                dismiss="alert" href="#">&times;</a><h4 class="alert-heading">error!</h4>'.$error.'</div>';
}
function showSuccess($success)
{
    echo '<div class="alert alert-success"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">&times;</a><h4 class="alert-heading">Login success!</h4>'.$success.'</div>';
}
}

class user
{
var $odb;

function __CONSTRUCT($odb)
{
    $this -> odb = $odb;
}
function loggedIn()
{
    if (isset($_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['ID']))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
function isAdmin()
{
    $SQL = $this -> odb -> prepare("SELECT `admin` FROM `Account` WHERE `ID` = :id");
    $SQL -> execute(array(':id' => $_SESSION['ID']));
    $rank = $SQL -> fetchColumn(0);
    if ($rank == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
    }
}`
```

my goal is it to display all the database variables of the logged in user on the profile page (Full name, Adress , Phone number) if someone could help me fix my code that would be really appreciated :)

Comment: `"how could i solve this issue"` - What issue?  What exactly isn't working?  Are your session values not printing?  Where do you set those session values?

Comment: for example when i use this string <h4 class="profile-user"><?php echo $_SESSION['firstname']; ?></h4> i get an error

Comment: Reading the error message would be a good first step.

Comment: @Vezuure What #David said!

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: lastname in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/profil.php on line 39 which is this string <h4 class="profile-user"><?php echo $_SESSION['lastname']; ?></h4>

Comment: what is the output of  $SQLGetID -> fetchColumn(0) ?

Comment: @krish it returns the ids

Comment: @Vezuure so where is your session assignment ? like  $_SESSION['firstname'] = $firstname;

Comment: alright. my fault. lets say i have to write a query and a function to retrieve the session variables off the db, how would i need to write that ?

Comment: Hey there. While it is commendable to try and at least hash the password, you'd be better off using the proven [password api](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php) that ships with php. The lack of salt in the final hash allows for too easy cracking of passwords in your database.

Answer (score 0):

this page profile.php

```
session_start();
$dbh = new PDO(" --- connection string --- ");
$user = new user($dbh);
if ($user->loggedIn()) {
    $stmt = $odb->prepare("SELECT `firstname`, `lastname`,`adress`,FROM `Account` WHERE ID=$_SESSION['ID'] LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
}
foreach ($row as $item)
{
    <h4 class="profile-user"><?php echo $item['firstname']; ?></h4>
    <p class="profile-job"><?php echo $item['lastname']; ?></p>
    <p class="profile-job"><?php echo $item['adress']; ?></p>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i received an error with this solution, i fixed it by changing the code in the profile.php to this.

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
      <!-- Page Widget -->

     <?php 
     $stmt = $odb->prepare("SELECT 'vorname', 'nachname','email',FROM 'Account' WHERE ID=$_SESSION[ID] LIMIT 1");
     $stmt->execute();
     $row = $stmt->fetch();

     foreach ((array) $row as $item){
       $vorname = $item['vorname']; // german word for firstname
       $nachname = $item['nachname']; // german word for lastname
       $email = $item['email']; // german word for email

     } ?>
      <h4 class="profile-user"><?php echo $vorname ?></h4>
```

but it doesnt seem to appear if i reload the screen.

looks really weird to me